# Android OpenGLES, getting number of fragments passed depth test/Occlusion Query?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es2

Afeter reading many blogs and searching on Internet, I did not get any sloution for getting number of fragments/pixels which are occludded or not occludded of the object on OpenGL ES3.0 Android version.
GL_SAMPLES_PASSED is not present on OpenGL ES3.0. 
Is there any way to get these occluded or non occluded fragments on Android OpenGl ES3.0?